# Boolean to take 1/0 as well as true/false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code. Is there a way I can re-write it so the Boolean (or any other method) will take 1 and 0 as well? Right now it only takes true/false as values. Can I do this without checking for 1/0 and then turning that into true/false? E.g. give a true or false just by using 1/0 as values.

```
$("#toggle").toggles({
  drag: true,
  click: true,
  text: {
    on: "ON",
    off: "OFF"
  },
  on: Boolean($("#container").attr("data-active")),
  animate: 150,
  easing: "swing",
  checkbox: null,
  clicker: null,
  width: 80,
  height: 16,
  type: "compact"
});
```

Comment: @janos Thank you! That worked, but only if I use parseInt() around it. That's the way to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pretty much never need `Boolean()` in JavaScript.

Simply use `!!$("#container").attr("data-active")` to convert the value to a boolean (negating a value converts it to boolean, negating it again undoes the negation)

Also, I would rather use `$("#container").data("active")` - by using `data()`, jQuery automatically converts the strings `true`/`false` to a boolean.

Comment: Might be a matter of taste but I actually use Boolean instead of !! - it is more verbose, but also a bit more clear what you are actually want to achieve.

Comment: Ah, data() worked. In the past I've had trouble with data() getting "old values" when loading dynamic content so I've used the attr instead. Thank you!